# SQLite3 Database disappears

Tags: sqlite, genymotion

I am using GenyMotion (latest version) to debug an Android app I'm building using Android Studio 2.3.3.
Today I tried to access the DB using ADB shell command, and I got the msg 'No such file or directory'.  This has happened several times in the past.  Fortunately, I was able to recreate the DB - the app creates the DB if it doesn't exist eg; if the app is run the first time. Can anyone tell me the reason for this happening?  And how it can be prevented?
I'm running Win 10 Pro with 16Gb memory.
Thanks

Comment: I hope you know that if you delete the app from the emulator the DB goes with it. Minor Point Next The Emulator need to be open to use the adb cmd. So It would be helpful if you posted your code by doing an edit to your question. By code I mean the syntax you use to PULL the DB file from the Emulator OTHER hint make a destination folder on your hard drive FIRST like C:\AASafe

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Also, I know that emulator has to be open to use ADB.